# Default prolog for all ZSH scripts?

Tags: shell, script, zsh

I have a file that contains several helper functions, meant to be used *only* in other ZSH scripts. I do not want them to be loaded with my profile. To make these functions available in my script, I would need to `source` this file.

Is it somehow possible to have automatic prolog script (or pre-script) loaded before *all* my ZSH scripts?

My current idea is to `alias -s` zsh extension to custom function that those all this for me:

- concatenate prolog file and current script
- calls zsh with such modified input

but for now I am somehow not able to do this (haven't sleep for almost a day). Please, does anyone have a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with the alias? I believe it would be fine to just make a short script which sources your script and then calls `zsh $@`:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
source my/script/path
$@
```

Then (if you named it libload) it works like this `./libload yourscript -options -options2`

You could also just put your code right in the file if that is easier. Also, it should be possible to add something like: `#!/bin/zsh /path/to/libload` to the top of each script but on my setup that doesn't work right ATM for some reason. Even so, it'd be nearly as easy to add `source /path/to/your/scripts` to each file.

It probably isn't a good idea to alias all calls to zsh. It is better for you to make a modified interpreter like I have shown than to replace the default ZSH command (or the default for any other interpreter).

Comment: yeah, but I would not like to type `libload` to start some my script. For now, aliasing `zsh` extension to zsh works fine, so I don't even write shebangs for my zsh scripts. This is just a matter of 'over'-optimization of the environment ;)

Comment: Then why not just use suffix aliases with `libload`? `alias -s zsh=libload` should work just fine.